# Goal seek function keeps reverting to the original values after finding solution

Tags: excel, vba, quantitative-finance

I am goal-seeking for the yield of a bond given the all-in=price. I made my code so that the goal-seeked yield, in cell G7, is copied to cell J11. However, I notice that, after performing the goal-seek, the values all revert to the ones before the goal-seek. Hence, the yield that I paste in cell J11 is the original yield, which is incorrect. The goal-seek function does find a solution however.

My code is below

```
Sub Repo_Price()
Dim name As String, i As Double

name = ActiveSheet.name
i = Range("G7").Value

Worksheets(name).Range("J10").Clear
Worksheets(name).Range("J11").Clear

With Application
    .MaxIterations = 500
    .MaxChange = 0.00000001
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets(name).Range("J10").Value = Worksheets(name).Range("J9").Value

'Preserving original date and YTM
Worksheets(name).Range("G1").Value = Worksheets(name).Range("G2").Value

'Calculating implied YTM
Worksheets(name).Range("G2").Value = Worksheets(name).Range("J3").Value
Range("G8").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("J10").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("G7")
Worksheets(name).Range("J11").Value = Worksheets(name).Range("G7").Value

'Returning to original date
Worksheets(name).Range("G2").Value = Worksheets(name).Range("G1").Value
Worksheets(name).Range("G1").Clear
Range("G7").Value = i

ActiveSheet.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code line count can be greatly reduced by simply setting cell values equal to each other rather copy/pasting. You can replace ALL of your first copy/paste with `Range("J10").Value = Range("J9").Value`. Make sure to qualify the range with a worksheet of course. Maybe after you do that, you can see the problem with your code since it will be much easier to read

Comment: Please rephrase your question/issue. Clarify the expected outcome.

Comment: @urdearboy. Thanks. I now see that my code was too convoluted. I just edited it. Will replace it with what I have now.

Comment: @PawelCzyz. Will do that now.

Comment: You can open your code and run it line by line using F8 key. Comment out Application.ScreenUpdating = False and check line by line where your outcome is being changed. Is it possible that your worksheet has some code behinde it?

Comment: @PawelCzyz. The code works fine everywhere else except at the goal-seek line. I see that the yield in G7 changes but, as soon as it is done iterating, the yield goes back to the original value. This is the issue that I am currently experiencing.

Comment: I might get you wrong, but before the goal seek you assign as `i = Range("G7").value`. Before the `ActiveSheet.Calculate` you assign `Range("G7").Value = i`. Therefore the value WILL BE the same as before. Just my guess, not tested though.